Show $\text{p.v.}\frac{x_{i}}{|x|^{n+1}}$ is tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$
Suppose dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not smaller than $2$ and $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, for $1\leq i\leq n$, define the functional
$$\langle\text{p.v.}\frac{x_{i}}{|x|^{n+1}},\varphi\rangle=\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{x_i}{|x|^{n+1}}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
I want to prove $\text{p.v.}\frac{x_{i}}{|x|^{n+1}}$ is tempered distribution for $1\leq i\leq n$. Here is what I have done:
To evaluate integral $I=\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{x_i}{|x|^{n+1}}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x$, I split it into two parts:
$$I=\int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq1}\frac{x_i}{|x|^{n+1}}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{|x|>1}\frac{x_i}{|x|^{n+1}}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x=I_1+I_2$$
For the second integral, since $|x_i|\leq|x|$, it is obvious that $|I_{2}|\leq\int_{|x|>1}\frac{|\varphi(x)|}{|x|^{n}}\mathrm{d}x<\Vert\varphi\Vert_{1}$. For $I_1$, it seems using Lagrange theorem is not feasible. How could I estimate
$$\int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq1}\frac{x_i}{|x|^{n+1}}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Any hint will be appreciated.
